# Android: Tab Content not appearing

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-tabhost

I have an info tab, which should have a listview, imageview and textview. For some reason the content is not showing.
Here is the code I use to set the tab up.

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4")


    .setContent(R.id.layout_tab_four).setIndicator(tabname4,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.information)));
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/layout_tab_four"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/infologo"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/infolistview"
                    android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="General"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />



            </ViewFlipper>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

List View Code:

```
infoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.infolistview);
infoListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item,
                this.fetchInfoList());
        infoList.setAdapter(infoListAdapter);
```

Fetch Info List Method:

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchInfoList() {
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();



        String listItem9 = "Visit Our Website";


        listItems.add(listItem9);


        return listItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use for select your tab this (after setting the content like you did):

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(X);
```

Where -1 < X < (numberoftabs -1) *//Do you like maths? :D*

Comment: That just opens the app on the info page, but the listview is still not showing

Comment: @EI756 you have said **For some reason the content is not showing.** If you want a help with the listview , show us the listview code. You have only shown the setup tab code.

Comment: This is not a problem with the listview, I have tried other views such as image views, and they are not showing either. It is just a blank screen.

Comment: @EI756 ... Why did you mark this as a correct answer?